# Pass Boolean to include tag in Android Data Binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am making common layout with data binding. I am having problem with passing boolean value to include tag.

I want achieve something like below

```
<include
   layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
   app:menuVisible="true"
   />
```

Here is `layout_toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="menuVisible"
            type="Boolean"/>

    </data>

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="@{menuVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"
        />
</layout>
```

What is appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass boolean as: `app:menuVisible="@{true}"`.

Comment: unfortunatly this doesn't work for me. Passing bound Observable<Boolean> does make it work.

Comment: Amazing! You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the type should be 'java.lang.Boolean', like this

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="menuVisible"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>

</data>
```

Comment: Primitive types classes does not need to mention full package.